# How to write problem formulation (CPXwriteprob) after user cut is added in callback (CPXcutcallbackadd)?

Tags: c++, cplex

I am trying to add user cuts in a cplex callback function. To inspect these cuts, I write an lp-file after a cut is added. However, no user cuts appear in the lp-file.

According to [this forum thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=82b92bee-4ac7-41dd-b1fc-606eae3514f3) (url: www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=82b92bee-4ac7-41dd-b1fc-606eae3514f3), cuts should appear starting with a 'u'.

relevant part of my code (based on example file bendersatsp.c):

```
int CPXPUBLIC benders_solver::benders_callback(CPXCENVptr env, void *cbdata, int wherefrom, void *cbhandle, int *useraction_p)
{
    int status = 0;
    int do_separate = 0;
    USER_CBHANDLE *user_cbhandle = (USER_CBHANDLE *)cbhandle;
    int purgeable;  
    *useraction_p = CPX_CALLBACK_DEFAULT;

    /* Decide if we want to separate cuts, depending on the parameter wherefrom */

    switch (wherefrom) {
    case CPX_CALLBACK_MIP_CUT_FEAS: // 115
    do_separate = 1;
    break;
    case CPX_CALLBACK_MIP_CUT_LAST: // 114: indicates that CPLEX is done adding cuts and the user has a last chance to add cuts
    do_separate = 1;
    break;
    case CPX_CALLBACK_MIP_CUT_LOOP: // 106: The callback was called from the cut loop CPLEX executes at each node.
    do_separate = 0;
    break;
    default:
    fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected value of wherefrom: %d\n", wherefrom);
    do_separate = 0;
    }

    if (!do_separate) goto TERMINATE;

    /* Get the current x solution */
    status = CPXgetcallbacknodex(env, cbdata, wherefrom, user_cbhandle->x, 0, user_cbhandle->num_x_cols - 1);
    if (status) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in CPXgetcallbacknodex: status = %d\n", status);
        goto TERMINATE;
    }

    CPXCLPptr lp_p;
    status = CPXgetcallbacklp(env, cbdata, wherefrom, &lp_p); // store master problem to lp_p

    changeSub_d(user_cbhandle, user_cbhandle->subenv, user_cbhandle->subproblem_d); 

    /* Solve the worker LP and look for a violated cut */
    CPXsetintparam(user_cbhandle->subenv, CPX_PARAM_PREIND, 0);

    int optstatus = CPXlpopt(user_cbhandle->subenv, user_cbhandle->subproblem_d);
    worker_lp_sol_stat = CPXgetstat(user_cbhandle->subenv, user_cbhandle->subproblem_d);

    /* Make cut */
    int matind[21000] = { 0 };              
    double matval[21000] = { 0 };
    double rhs[1];
    char sense[1];
    int nbnz{ 0 };      

    status = addBendersCut(user_cbhandle, worker_lp_sol_stat, env, lp_p, cbdata, wherefrom);

    int purgeable = CPX_USECUT_FORCE;
    status = CPXcutcallbackadd(env, cbdata, wherefrom, nbnz, rhs[0], sense[0], matind, matval, purgeable);
    status = CPXwriteprob(masterenv, masterproblem, "cback.lp", "LP");


    /* Tell CPLEX that cuts have been created */
    if (status)
        goto TERMINATE;

    *useraction_p = CPX_CALLBACK_SET;

    TERMINATE:

    /* If an error has been encountered, we fail */

    if (status) *useraction_p = CPX_CALLBACK_FAIL;

    return status;

} /* END benders_callback */



bool benders_solver::startSolve()
{
    loadGeneralData(sol);

    // Initialize the CPLEX environment 
    masterenv = CPXopenCPLEX(&status);
    subenv = CPXopenCPLEX(&status);

    loadMasterProblem(); 
    loadSubProblem(); 

    USER_CBHANDLE user_cbhandle;
    int separate_fractional_solutions = 1;

    /* Init the cut callback data structure */
    status = init_user_cbhandle(&user_cbhandle, separate_fractional_solutions);

    /* Let MIP callbacks work on the original model */
    status = CPXsetintparam(env, CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_CallbackReducedLP, CPX_OFF);
    status = CPXsetintparam(env, CPX_PARAM_PRELINEAR, 0);
    status = CPXsetintparam(env, CPX_PARAM_MIPCBREDLP, 0);
    status = CPXsetintparam(env, CPXPARAM_Threads, 1);  
    /* Turn on traditional search for use with control callbacks */
    status = CPXsetintparam(env, CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_Search,      CPX_MIPSEARCH_TRADITIONAL); 

    if (user_cbhandle->separate_fractional_solutions) {
        status = CPXsetusercutcallbackfunc(env, benders_callback, user_cbhandle);
    }

    /* Optimize the problem and obtain solution status */
    status = CPXsetintparam(masterenv, CPX_PARAM_PREIND, 0);
    status = CPXsetdblparam(masterenv, CPX_PARAM_TILIM, 300);
    status = CPXsetstrparam(masterenv, CPXPARAM_WorkDir, "c:/cplex/");
    status = CPXsetintparam(masterenv, CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_File, 2);
    status = CPXsetdblparam(masterenv, CPXPARAM_WorkMem, 6000);
    status = CPXsetintparam(masterenv, CPX_PARAM_MEMORYEMPHASIS, 1); 
    status = CPXmipopt(masterenv, masterproblem);

    status = CPXsetlogfile(masterenv, NULL);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: It looks like the forum that you linked to is down at the moment. With that said, I believe you can expect that user cuts added with [CPXaddusercuts](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/mipapi/addusercuts.html) (before a solve) will show up when using `CPXwriteprob`, but not user cuts that are added dynamically during the tree search in a callback. Before providing an answer to this question I'll wait until the forum link is back up to check what you are referring to.

Comment: The developerWorks forums seems to be operational, but your link is still not working. Can you try fixing it?

Comment: Link is working fine on my machine... I added the full url, but do not know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write the LP, it looks like you are using the original model object (i.e., `masterproblem`):

```
status = CPXwriteprob(masterenv, masterproblem, "cback.lp", "LP");
```

Instead, you'll need to use the node LP, like so:

```
CPXLPptr _lp;
status = CPXgetcallbacknodelp(env, cbdata, wherefrom, &_lp);
CPXwriteprob(env, _lp, "cback.lp", "LP");
```

As mentioned in the forum post you linked to:

> the CPXcutcallbackadd() functions takes no arguments to provide names.
>   In the cback.lp file, the cuts you added will have a name that starts
>   with 'u', followed by a number. So you can find which rows are cuts
>   that were added by you but you cannot easily map them back to things
>   in your code

Another minor point worth mentioning (and to clarify what I mentioned in the comments) is that, *outside of the callback*, your cuts will *not* show up when using `CPXwriteprob` (i.e., any cuts that were added dynamically during the tree search in a callback will not be exported). However, if you add user cuts *before* optimization using [CPXaddusercuts](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/mipapi/addusercuts.html), then they will.

Another similar question to yours can be found on the developerWorks forum [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=bef8f94f-d2db-4de5-8de2-7d49ca332c54&ps=25).